# I forgot to create new xcdatamodel on deleting an attribute. Now it crashes only for few users

Tags: ios, core-data

I did a release version 21 where a new attribute was added in an entity. Then again in version 22 I removed that new attribute from that entity. I forgot to create new `xcdatamodel` for this change (one which went in version 22). I tested the app and it was working fine.

The problem is it is crashing for some users when code try to access persistence container (I'm using `INSPersistentContainer` library). But it doesn't crash on local development.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: INSPersistentContainer = {
        let stack = INSDataStackContainer(name: "MyDb")
        stack.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        stack.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        stack.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { desc, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                abort()
            }
        })
        return stack
    }()
```

Logically it should crash for everyone because I didn't create new `xcdatamodel` for new version but it is crashing only for few users.

When I used `sqlite db browser` to browse data of app on my mobile the attribute that was removed in version 22 doesn't exist. So somehow iOS did the migration by itself.

I want to release a new version which should not have that removed attribute for everyone who is upgrading to that version regardless from which version they upgrade. How can I make sure of this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else has this problem, our problem was when we introduced constraint on entity it already had some data which was in violation of the constraints. Core data constraints work fine with new entries but it fails to migrate if your data is already in violation of constraints you provide.

P.S. If you have minor changes in your core data schema, iOS will automatically attempt migration even if you don't provide new `xcdatamodel`.